# PHP array - start at beginning if over

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with 3 entries like that:

```
0 => "Banana",
1 => "Apple",
2 => "Strawberry"
```

Now, when using a for-loop like:

```
for($i = 1; $i < $foo; $i++) {
  $myarray[$i] = $fruitarray[$i];
}
```

And `$i` gets higher than 2, we run out of this `$fruitarray`. So what I want to do now is always to start at the beginning of the array when it's over. So that 3 outputs "Banana", 7 "Apple" etc.

What is the best practice to achieve this (especially if `$fruitarray` contains many entries)?

Comment: You want to create an infinite loop, is that it?

Comment: You dropped your banana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for($i = 1; $i < $foo; $i++) {
  $myarray[$i] = $fruitarray[$i%3];
}
```

Notice the $i%3, this is pronounced "i mod 3" and it means divide i by 3, and return the leftovers. So, 4%3=1, 7%3=1, 11%3=2, etc.

Just make sure $foo is more than 3, and this should wrap around. If $fruitarray is arbitrarily bigger than 3 items, use

```
$i%count($fruitarray)
```

Comment: The only concern is hard-coding the size of the fruit array.

Comment: $i%count($fruitarray) , this was written with the original answer

Answer (score 5):

This is generally accomplished using the modulo operator.

```
for($i = 1; $i < $foo; $i++) {
    $myarray[$i] = $fruitarray[$i % count($fruitarray)];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Comment: Won't this still stop once `$i` >= `$foo`? -- You could just fix that by removing the for loop condition.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu - yes, but I was assuming that was what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to check for when `$i` is equal to `$foo - 1` and reset it to `1`:

```
for($i = 1; $i < $foo; $i++) {
  $myarray[$i] = $fruitarray[$i];
  if($i == ($foo - 1))
     $i = 1;
}
```

Comment: This creates an infinite loop if `$foo > count($fruitarray)` which is almost certainly the case.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use the modulus operator (Modulus remainder of $a divided by $b)

```
for($i = 1; $i < $foo; $i++) {
  $j=$i%count($fruitarray);
  $myarray[$i] = $fruitarray[$j];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 0):

Doing this with eager code is essentially intractable, as it would cause an infinite loop:

```
$i = 0;
$numFruits = count($fruitarray);
while (true) { // infinite loop!
    $myarray[$++i] = $fruitarray[$i % $numFruits];
}
```

But you can come up with working code if, instead of an array, you use a function to fetch the value:

```
function getFruitAt($index) use ($fruitarray) {
    $numFruits = count($fruitarray);
    $realIndex = $index % $numFruits;
    return $fruitarray[$realIndex];
}
```

Or, if you want to get fancy, you can use a [generator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) or define your own [Iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) type.